# Improving a regex search pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Assume I have a file that looks like this:

```
'''
MFTF2LH_LSetC1_D-10_hot50_fa00_bpmax
MFTF2LH_LSetC1_D-11_hot50_fa00_bpmax
MFTF2LH_LSetC1_D-01_hot56_fa00_bpmax
MFTF2LH_LSetC1_D-02_hot56_fa00_bpmax
MFTF2LH_LSetC1_D-03_hot56_fa00_bpmax
MFTF2LH_LSetC1_D-04_hot50_fa00_bpmax
MFTF2LH_LSetC1_D-07_hot43_fa00_bpmax
MFTF2LH_LSetC1_D-10_hot56_fa00_bpmax
'''
```

but has millions or rows.

What I want to do is read it line by line and disregard those lines that feature:

- _D-**XX**_hot**YY** with **XX** in [01, 07] inclusive and **YY** = 43 **or** 50
- _D-**XX**_hot**56** with **XX** in [08, 11] inclusive

so for the example lines above, only the last three would be disregarded.

I am using this `regex` pattern which does the trick ([test here](https://regex101.com/r/7kGuC3/1)):

```
pattern = '(_D-0[1-7]_hot(43|50)|_D-0[8,9]_hot56|_D-1[0,1]_hot56)'
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way to do it since I just want to return a boolean; no groups or anything.

I am a total beginner in `regex` btw.

Comment: Use `if re.search(): #matched, do something`. And use non-capturing groups if you care about the "groups".

Comment: That's clear but with the current `pattern`? I will look into non-capturing groups. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, your pattern is bad because the alternatives match at the same location. Use [`_D-(?:1[01]_hot56|0(?:[89]_hot56|[1-7]_hot(?:43|50)))`](https://regex101.com/r/7kGuC3/3). I see no problem here since you say your pattern works. I think it is a good idea to read line by line.

Comment: @Sayse because `'.._D-09_hot43..'` for example has to stay.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would accept that as an answer in case you are interested.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think that you forgot the word `not` in at least one of your comments. xD

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, how about some unix tool one-liner?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Fire in the hole!

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, get your "fire" in some other "hole"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Did you *really* get offended?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, in online you can say anything. I know that in offline I would not give a good chance for such jokes

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Do you even know what *"Fire in the hole"* means ?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, I don't play computer games. As for you ... had you even been in army? Or you just saw films about it on television?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may improve your pattern by making alternatives match at different locations in the string only.

Use

```
rx = re.compile(r'_D-(?:1[01]_hot56|0(?:[89]_hot56|[1-7]_hot(?:43|50)))')
# .... Read the file line by line ...
if not rx.search(line):
    # Ok, process
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7kGuC3/3)

**Pattern details**:

- `_D-` - a literal substring
- `(?:` - start of the non-capturing group (no memory buffers are created for groups unlike with capturing groups) matching:

  - `1[01]_hot56` - `1`, then `0` or `1` and then `_hot56`
  - `|`  - or
  - `0` -  a `0` char and then
  - `(?:` - second non-capturing group

    - `[89]_hot56` - `8` or `9` and then `_hot56`
    - `|` or
    - `[1-7]_hot(?:43|50)` - a digit from `1` to `7`, then `_hot` and then either `43` or `50`
  - `)` - end of the second non-capturing group
- `)` - end of the first non-capturing group

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `grep` with `-v` (revert matches):

```
grep -Ev "D-[0][1-7]_hot(?:43|50)|D-(?:08|09|10|11)_hot56" raw.txt > filtered.txt
```

It matches exactly what you don't want and then revert the matches.